# What is the intuition of attacks on ring lwe?

Tags: ring-lwe

I know that there are several attacks on ring lwe. But I am not sure why they work.
Does anyone have intuition of such attacks?

What is the common idea used?
Reducing the Search space (modulus space)?

I want to know them.